# Boolean expression involving Enum and Int

Tags: c#

I have a simple enum with a few values

```
Enum Status{
Available, 
Taken,
Sold//and many more
}
```

I want to check whether the status is somewhere in between the possible values(assuming the values are written in such an order that the lowest are the beginning of a process, and the last ones are the final steps of the process)

Something like

```
Status s1;//Some value
if(s1<5 && s1>3)
//The value is one of the enum values in those range
//(for example the job has already been accepted, but has still not been
//shipped)
```

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Just cast the status to int and do your checks:  (int)s1

Comment: Someone delete this question, I couldn't figure out how to search for it correctly.

Comment: You can delete it yourself. There is a button available next to edit. We are not going to do it for you.

Comment: I can't, since there's an answer already.

Comment: It should be possible since the answer is at score 0. What is the message you get?

Comment: Still won't let me.

Comment: @master2080 You can flag it and choose the moderator intervention to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign integer values to your enum and then check.

```
enum Status
{
    Available = 1, 
    Taken = 2,
    Sold = 3
    //and many more
}

Status s1; // any value
if ((int)s1 <= 5 && (int)s1 >= 3)
```

Comment: Well since Enums are ints by default, I guess not assigning numbers already puts them in order, is that correct?

Comment: @master2080 Correct, starting at index 0.